# Open Context Menu On Selected TreeView Node

Tags: .net, treeview, contextmenu

What is the problem with this code ?

```
 Private Sub trvHeader_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles trvHeader.NodeMouseClick
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
                trvHeader.SelectedNode = e.Node
                Dim p As Point = New Point(e.X, e.Y)

                mnuRoot.Show(p)
            End If
        End Sub
```

the context menu does not open in right position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContextMenuStrip.Show(Point) overload requires the point to be in screen coordinates.   Fix:

```
 mnuRoot.Show(trvHeader, p)
```

or use Control.PointToScreen()